# Creating native memory leak in Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

Consider following code:

MyClass.java:

```
public class MyClass {

   public native void createMemoryLeak();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
      myObject.createMemoryLeak();
   }
}
```

MyClass.c:

```
#include <MyClass.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_createMemoryLeak(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
   char * leaked_array = malloc(sizeof(char)*100000); // This is going to be leaked
}
```

`MyClass` has a native method `createMemoryLeak()`. In this method, there is a char array allocated using `malloc()`. However, this memory is not freed explicitly.

I wonder what happens to this memory when method goes out of scope. 
Will this code create a memory leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this will create a memory leak. Java doesn't care what the native code does as long as it doesn't crash.

So you need to find a way to clean up all native resources. The usual way is to wrap the native resources in some Java object and add `native` methods to dispose the resources when you're done with them.